# ArrayList from File (of Abstract class)

Tags: java, arraylist, abstract

I have a project I'm working on and pretty much I need to make an ArrayList of the Abstract Class `AbstractCustomer`; the ArrayList needs to be made up of AbstractCustomer read in from either a data or text file, so I'm trying to do it through a data file but can't wrap my head around it?

This is my class:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.*;

public abstract class AbstractCustomer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private final int MIN_LENGTH = 10;

    public AbstractCustomer() {

    }

    public AbstractCustomer(String name, String phoneNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;

        //Phone number is less than 10, but what if it's more than 10?
        //Assignment doesn't say, so I will assume it can be more than 10.
        //Ya know country codes 1845 and all that
        if (phoneNumber.length() < MIN_LENGTH) {
            throw new NumberFormatException("Phone number must be at least 10 digits long.");
        }

        //Parse the long, so this will rule out anything else except digit.
        try {
            Long.parseLong(phoneNumber);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Phone number can only contain digits, please no dashes ('-') or spaces (' ')");
        }

    }

    abstract double returnDiscountPrice(double itemCost);

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        AbstractCustomer other = (AbstractCustomer) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (phoneNumber == null) {
            if (other.phoneNumber != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!phoneNumber.equals(other.phoneNumber))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AbstractCustomer[name=" + name + ", phoneNumber=" + phoneNumber + "]";
    }


}
```

And this is what I was trying to do:

```
public void createDataFile() {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Frank\\Desktop\\Assignment\\abstract.dat");
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        outputStream.writeObject(HOW DO I WRITE THE ABSTRACT CLASS TO A FILE HERE????);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What did you try and why did it not work? Exactly where did you get stuck? Could you please clean out the code that is not of concern for your question?

Comment: You can't write a class to a file. You can write an object to a file though?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what you write using IO is an object, not a class. You can read in [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html) that:

> Abstract classes cannot be instantiated, but they can be subclassed.

What you need to do, is either delete the abstract identifier (i don't see any abstract methods) or inherit this abstract class.

Only then will you be able to instantiate objects of the class (Not)AbstractCustomer and Serialize them using IO.

The only reason that your abstract class is Serializable, is for the classes that extend It, to be serializable as well. I hope this was clear enough.

Here's an example of serialization: (**Note that i created a nested class that inherits the abstract class. Don't write It that way. I made it only for demonstration purposes. the main method won't work in that case**):

```
// this cannot be serialized because no objects can be instantiated
public abstract class SerializationTest {

// this can be, because it's not abstract
public static class SerializationTestB extends SerializationTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

        // instantiation of an object that you want to write to file
        SomeObject obj = new SomeObject(param, param, param);
        SomeObject obj2 = new SomeObject(param, param, param);
        SomeObject obj3 = new SomeObject(param, param, param);
        SomeObject obj4 = new SomeObject(param, param, param);
        SomeObject obj5 = new SomeObject(param, param, param);
        SomeObject obj6 = new SomeObject(param, param, param);

        // an object that represents the path of the file
        File f = new File("some/path/here");

        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f))); 
        out.writeObject(obj);
        out.writeObject(obj2);
        out.writeObject(obj3);
        out.writeObject(obj4);
        out.writeObject(obj5);
        out.writeObject(obj6);

        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I can't remove it, it's an assignment and the class NEEDS to be abstract for whatever stupid reason. Anyway I tried to inherit from it but then when I go to read the file I wrote from that inherited class into an ArrayList of AbstractClass I get nothing.